# iOS - Can I make the status bar look like the in-call

Tags: ios, statusbar, in-call

I need the status bar to look like there is a call and execute certain piece of code when the user taps the status bar.
Is it possible. I can't find any API allowing me to play with the status bar

Comment: I don't think so. you can only use that if you're recording or on a VoIP

Comment: You can hide the status bar and make your own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You can use this to show messages in the status bar (or "like they are in the status bar"):

https://github.com/petersantino/TWStatus

And you can put a gestureRecognizer on top of it or a button in order to catch the tap of the user ( enabling it only when the desired event is happening).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It looks cool actually. It's like the one used in Mailbox but it doesn't suit my needs. I researched a lot and there is no way to tweak the status bar to look like an in-call status bar. Just like the guys that commented above said.

Comment: Of course I can make my own but it would be great amount of work to mimic the status bar. And I guess I can't get information like carrier name, signal strength etc. Anyway thanks to all for replying